# How to get all semantic data that is common between three classes using SPARQL?

Tags: sparql, semantics

I have a scenario where the user can select multiple classes and i need to build dynamic SPARQL query to fetch all the data that satisfies all the relationships thats exist (if any )between all selected classes. How do i achieve this?

Suppose the user selects three classes-  Population, Drugname,SideEffects. Now he tries to find all the common data that exists between these three classes. How do i  build a SPARQL query to achieve this? I need a sample SPARQL query that joins these three classes.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "common between"?  Do you mean that they all have the same value for some property (or are all the value of some property of some other resource)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to retrieve properties for which some resources have the same value (and so you probably want to retrieve that value, too), you can use a query like this:

```
select ?p ?o where {
  dbpedia:Bob_Dylan ?p ?o .
  dbpedia:Tom_Waits ?p ?o .
  dbpedia:The_Byrds ?p ?o .
}
```

[SPARQL results from DBpedia](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select%20?p%20?o%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20dbpedia%3aBob_Dylan%20?p%20?o%20.%0D%0A%20%20dbpedia%3aTom_Waits%20?p%20?o%20.%0D%0A%20%20dbpedia%3aThe_Byrds%20?p%20?o%20.%0D%0A%7D&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

```
p                                                o
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type  http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing
http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type  http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Agent
http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type  http://schema.org/MusicGroup
http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type  http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/YagoLegalActor
http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type  http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/YagoLegalActorGeo
http://purl.org/dc/terms/subject                 http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Rock_and_Roll_Hall_of_Fame_inductees
http://dbpedia.org/ontology/recordLabel          http://dbpedia.org/resource/Asylum_Records
http://dbpedia.org/ontology/genre                http://dbpedia.org/resource/Rock_music
http://dbpedia.org/property/genre                http://dbpedia.org/resource/Rock_music
http://dbpedia.org/property/label                http://dbpedia.org/resource/Asylum_Records
http://dbpedia.org/property/wordnet_type         http://www.w3.org/2006/03/wn/wn20/instances/synset-musician-noun-1
```

You could also use a query like this to find the subjects that are related to all three of these individuals by some particular property (but on DBpedia it doesn't have any answers):

```
select ?s ?p where {
  ?s ?p dbpedia:Bob_Dylan, dbpedia:Tom_Waits, dbpedia:The_Byrds .
}
```